Gluing of sheaves via sheafication
Setting.
Let $X$ be a topological spaced, and let $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an open covering. Denote by $U_{ik}$ any intersection $U_i\cap U_k$.
Suppose that on each $U_i$ there is a ring sheaf $O_i$ and that, for any (ordered) pair $i,k\in I$, there is an isomorphism $$\phi_{ik}:O_i|_{U_{ik}}\to O_k|_{U_{ik}}$$ such that, for all $i,h,k\in I$:

$\phi_{ii}$ is the identity;
$\phi_{ik}$ and $\phi_{ki}$ are the inverse of each other;
$\phi_{hk}|_{U_{ihk}}\circ \phi_{ih}|_{U_{ihk}}=\phi_{ik}|_{U_{ihk}}$.

I'd like to know if the presheaf $O$ that I describe below is indeed a gluing, and precisely:

Is $O$ a ring sheaf?
Is $O|_{U_i}$ isomorphic to $O_i$ for all $i$?

Construction of $O$.
Let $S_i:=\bigsqcup_{x\in U_i}O_{i,x}$, the disjoint union of the stalks of $O_i$ at every point. Define $S:=\bigsqcup_{i\in I}S_i$, and define a relation $\sim$ on $S$   as follows:

$(s\in S_i)\sim (s'\in S_k)$ if and only if it is true that $s\in O_{i,x}$,  $s'\in O_{k,x}$ with $x\in U_{ik}$, and that $\phi_{ik,x}(s)=s'$.

It's easy to see that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, from the three axioms on the various $\phi_{ik}$, and so let $\mathcal S:=S/\sim$.
Now define a presheaf $O$ on $X$ as follows:

for any open set $U\subset X$, let $O(U)$ be the set of maps $\sigma:U\to \mathcal S$ such that, for all $i\in I$, the map $\sigma|_{U_i\cap U}$ has this property: any $x\in U_i\cap U$ has a open set $x\in  W\subset U_i\cap U$ on which $\sigma(w)=[s_w]_\sim$, for all $w\in W$ and a fixed $s\in O_i(W)$;
the restrictions are then the usual restrictions of maps.

Such $O$ is surely a presheaf, and  there is an obvious structure of ring on any $O_(U)$, that is preserved by the restrictions.
To see that $O|_{U_i}$ is isomorphic to $ O_i$ I replaced $O_i$ with its sheafication, that is constructed similarly to $O$ and should make more evident the isomorphism.
Do you think that this gluing construction is ok or do you see any issue? I didn't made all the checks explicit in this question because they are quite tedious, but the definition of $O$ should be precise enough. Thanks for any advice.

It is a theorem (a common exercise, really) that there is unique data (up to isomorphism) of a sheaf (of rings) $\mathscr{O}$ and isomorphisms $\psi_j:\mathscr{O}|{U_j}\cong O_j$ such that $\phi{jk}\circ\psi_j=\psi_k$ for all $j,k$ but I personally proved this differently and would need to think further if your construction is also viable
